# How to extract string from a long string

Tags: r, python-3.x

I'm struggling to extract strings from a long string which is a row of a csv file with python or R. The long string is

```
"Zhao, Sihai@Univ Penn::Cai, T. Tony@Univ Penn::Li, Hongzhe@Univ Penn"
```

And the results should be

```
"Zhao, Sihai" "Cai, T. Tony" "Li, Hongzhe"
```

Comment: Questions that do not specify a single programming language are normally considered as too broad.

Comment: Do you want to do this in R or Python? You've specified both.

Comment: What are the criteria for the strings you want to find? Technically, I could solve the problem by slicing the strings with hand-coded indices, but that wouldn't generalize. What are you trying to keep, in general? And, what are you trying to reject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can do

```
a <- "Zhao, Sihai@Univ Penn::Cai, T. Tony@Univ Penn::Li, Hongzhe@Univ Penn"

sub('(^.+)@.*$', '\\1', unlist(strsplit(a, '::')))
#[1] "Zhao, Sihai"  "Cai, T. Tony" "Li, Hongzhe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
tmp_str = "Zhao, Sihai@Univ Penn::Cai, T. Tony@Univ Penn::Li, Hongzhe@Univ Penn"
names = [s.split("@")[0] for s in tmp_str.split("::")]
print(names)
```

And the output is 
`['Zhao, Sihai', 'Cai, T. Tony', 'Li, Hongzhe']`

Answer (score 0):

Does it enough for you ?
**Input:**

```
str = "Zhao, Sihai@Univ Penn::Cai, T. Tony@Univ Penn::Li, Hongzhe@Univ Penn"
parsed = x.replace('@Univ Penn','').split("::")
print(parsed)
```

**Output:**

```
['Zhao, Sihai', 'Cai, T. Tony', 'Li, Hongzhe']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
 s = "Zhao, Sihai@Univ Penn::Cai, T. Tony@Univ Penn::Li, Hongzhe@Univ Penn"
l=s.replace('@Univ Penn','').split("::")
s=str(l)
s2=s[1:-1]
print(s2)
```

**output**

```
'Zhao, Sihai', 'Cai, T. Tony', 'Li, Hongzhe'
```